# Digitalocean App: failed to load /usr/app/start.sh

Tags: python, docker, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I really don't get this. I am trying to deploy my python app to from GitHub to docker using gunicorn to start the app. But I keep getting this error after the build is successful but before deployment can begin

```
starting non-root container [./start.sh]: creating process: failed to load /usr/app/start.sh: exec format error
```

I have tried changing the permission for the start.sh file but it doesnt change.
This is my start.sh

```
gunicorn -b :5000 --access-logfile - --error-logfile - pixelshop:app
```

This is my docker

```
FROM python:latest
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY . .
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y libgl1-mesa-dev
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install Flask
RUN pip install gunicorn
RUN chmod +x start.sh
ENTRYPOINT  ./start.sh
```

Comment: Does adding a "shebang" line `#!/bin/sh` at the start of the script help?

Comment: If you are on windows set LF on `start.sh`.

Comment: Add `start.sh` to your question. Based on whether your .sh file should start with `bash` or `sh`, you should add `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/sh` to the first line, exactly the first line.

Answer (score 9):

I think there are two things that could be happening here.

1. As David Maze suggested, make sure to include the shebang as the ***first line*** in your `entrypoint.sh` file.
2. My issue is that my *new M1* Macbook Pro was using ARM64 architecture while DigitalOcean seems to only support AMD64 images. You can check your docker image with:

```sh
> docker inspect <YOUR_IMAGE_ID> --format '{{.Architecture}}'
arm64
```

If you see `arm64` you then you should specify `amd64` architecture in your `Dockerfile` as such:

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python:latest
# Rest for Dockerfile...
```

Hope this helps someone in the future becuase I was beyond frustrated trying to figure out what changed when deploying a new image.

Comment: Yep, this is the problem I had after getting an M1 MBP. Thanks!